# Can one use a year-round warming tray for Pesach? How?

Tags: halacha, passover, cooking-bishul, chametz-leaven, appliances

Year-round, pans of food and foil-wrapped food are placed on an electric warming tray; the foods within are not kosher for Passover. What's the easiest way to permissibly use the tray for Passover? Can one just use it as is, since the food doesn't touch it directly? If not, can one use it covered with foil? Or what?

Comment: Hi Sherrill and welcome to Mi Yodeya, thanks for bringing your question here, hope to see you around the site.

Comment: I second nikmasi's welcome. I've edited the question per [the FAQ list](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) ("Questions that appear to be requests for personal practical advice will be either edited to more general wording or closed").

Answer (score 3):

I asked this question a couple of years ago to my LOR and was told that I should clean the surface as well as possible (two rounds of EZ OFF will do) and I should then cover the surface with aluminum foil.

Comment: User2451 Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. You might also think about adopting a new user name, unless you're particularly fond of the number 2451. :)

Comment: I second SethJ's welcome, and am writing merely to advise that you include your LOR's name in the answer if he wouldn't mind: this would provide readers with more information to go on. Also, if you know his reason for his answer, that'd be a great addition to the answer.